# transition starts after page loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to add transition on divs when the page loaded. But having some problem to make it works.

**template**

```
<header>
    <transition name="slideLeft">
        <div v-show="loaded" class="contents content-left"></div>
    </transition>
    <transition name="slideRight">
        <div v-show="loaded" class="contents content-right"></div>
    </transition>
</header>
```

**script**

```
data(){
    return {
        loaded: false,
    };
},
created(){
    this.onLoaded();
},
methods: {
    onLoaded() {
      this.loaded = true;
    }
}
```

**css**

```
.slideLeft-enter-active{
    width: 400px;
}
.slideRight-enter-active{
    width: 400px;
}
header {
    background-color: #1b1d1f;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
header .contents {
    transition: 2s;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #151618;
}
```

can someone point out what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Change your style code

```css
<style>
  .slide-left-enter,
  .slide-right-enter {
    width: 0 !important;
  }

  .slide-left-enter-to,
  .slide-right-enter-to {
    width: 400px !important;
  }

  header {
    background-color: #1b1d1f;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  header .contents {
    width: 400px;
    transition: all 2s;
    background-color: #151618;
    color: #fff;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: @iamPanda In my code is `slide-left`, not `slideLeft`. So you need to change the value of the name attribute of the transition to `slide-left` and `slide-right`.